# If Sharedpreference changed condition for an if function.

Tags: java, android

I want to make an if function that it's condition is to check if a sharedpreference changed or not, any idea on how to make this, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Context.getSharedPreferences() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, to register a listener that will be invoked when a change in the `preference` occurs. Don't forget to call `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, when you don't need it anymore, or you leave the Activity/Fragment

Comment: `do remember to call unregister` ? ;)

Comment: @Simon, thanks. I meant *don't forget*